# XUnit IAsyncLifetime and AutoFixture attribute substitution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, nsubstitute, autofixture

I want to use the attribute substitution method from AutoFixture, however, I need to use IAsyncLifetime and bootstrap another library, I have a base test  class that does this and any tests using the library inherits from it:

```
    public class BaseTest : IDisposable, IAsyncLifetime
    {
        public BaseTest()
        {
             Resolver = new ServiceCollection()//...add services
                        .BuildServiceProvider();
        }
        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            await BootstrapAsync();
        }

        private async Task BootstrapAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            // How do I share Resolver from my fixture attribute to here?

            var bootstrapper = Resolver.GetRequiredService<IBootstrapper>();
            await bootstrapper.StartAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

Example of test:

```
    public class MainTest : BaseTest
    {
// Must be able to use same Resolver used in Boostrap
        [Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
        public Task Does_the_thing(MyService service) 
        {
        } 
    }
```

The attribute definition, where I can create my resolver, but how do I use it in the boostrap?

```
           public AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute()
            : base(() => new Fixture()
                .Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization() {  ConfigureMembers = true } 
                 ))
        {
        }
```